# Are there projects visualizing and analyzing historical transaction data?

Tags: transactions

I know blockchain.info etc, but I'm looking for things beyond simple timelines of transaction volume and the like. I was thinking towards scientific projects that aim at discovering patterns in the historical data, for instance:

- are there addresses that accumulate large amounts of btc?
- are there interesting transaction pattern, e. g. prolonged transaction "ping pong" between address pairs, "star patterns" where a single address sends out transactions to a large group of others, etc
- are there amounts that seem to get passed on along a long chain of addresses?

Note that those are just examples I made up to illustrate what kind of angle I'm looking for: a more open-ended, scientific analysis rather than trading advice. That same notion makes it hard to search for projects, so I'm hoping that someone might happen to know something.

Comment: I rewrote the question in the hope to make it more answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Check this website. It has summary of the tools available http://block-chain-analysis.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the "things like that".  There are lots of different things that might be of interest to some people and not to others, and so each site has a few reports or charts but none are comprehensive.

Two examples: [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) has a number of reports in the bottom right of their main page under the 'Other Bitcoin links' that has some reports that some might find interesting.  [Bconomy](http://charts.bconomy.com/) has a number of charts that provide information about blocks and transactions.

Comment: I understand. I rewrote the question hoping to be more specific this time.